# Add textbox input to existing StartInfo.Arguments

Tags: c#, arguments

I have a snippet of the code I am trying to fix:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
//p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; // This line will not create any new window for command prompt.
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\dscheck.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/full groups /clean";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = argTextBox.Text;
p.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("y");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
string s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(s); //Shows a Popup of the output from Dscheck
//String s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Here is my issue:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/full groups /clean";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = argTextBox.Text;
```

I am trying to pass the `tscheck.exe /full /groups /clean {UID}` - The *UID* is inputted in the `argTextBox`, but it is not working. It reads: `p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/full groups /clean"`; and takes the argTextBox and doesn't place anything.

Any ideas how to add the textbox input into the existing argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/full groups /clean " + argTextBox.Text;
```

Instead of assigning the text from the text box, append it to the existing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just append at the end of the current arguments parameters (with a space separator of course)

```
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/full groups /clean " + argTextBox.Text;
    p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

in the second assignment you are replacing the value assigned before, replace these lines:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/full groups /clean";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = argTextBox.Text;
```

with:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/full groups /clean {0}", argTextBox.Text);
```